# Wordpress single image lightbox gallery

Tags: wordpress, image-gallery, galleryview

I am trying to create lightbox gallery in Wordpress. I would like to display gallery as single image. When user clicks on image lightbox opens and you can navigate (left-right) through gallery.

I tried many plugins but none of them gives me an option to display gallery as single image. I can write code but but I would like to know is there a plugin for a kind of gallery I described above (for easier adding of future galleries).

If you know any other solution please let me know. I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something like this recently with the native WordPress galleries, a little CSS, and the lightbox plugin I was already using on a site: dFactory's [Responsive Lightbox.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-lightbox/)

The plugin will show your entire gallery in a lightbox even if you hide all but the first slide. If you don't want this to effect all your galleries either create a alternate page template with a different ID, or enclose the gallery/galleries in a div in the text editor. Here's the CSS:

```
#your-content .gallery .gallery-item {display:none;}
#your-content .gallery .gallery-item:first-child {display:block;}
```

I used it to create a set of albums where the first image served as the album cover. This little bit below gave me six images across with captions, where you click on the single image and get a full gallery for each.

```
#your-content .gallery {
  width:14.6%;
  float:left;
  clear:none;
  position:relative;
  margin:1%;
  padding:0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at Owl Carousel! 
Preferable together with Advanced Custom Fields

Maybe you can take some inspiration from this: 
http://www.internetkultur.at/simple-slider-advanced-custom-fields-owl-carousel/